# Error on closing a file in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I have a function that encrypts and upload a file from my system to a server. After uploading the file when I am trying to close, there is an error occurs. The error code is 12030. The upload section of my code is shown below. What is the problem in that code which generate error on closing the file.

```
CFile   fp;
UINT uNoOfBytes;
UINT uNoOfEncBytes;
bool bIsFinalBlock = false;
BYTE*   pBuf = NULL;
HINTERNET m_hRequest;


if(!fp.Open(szFilePath, CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareDenyNone, &err))
{
    AfxThrowFileException(err.m_cause, err.m_lOsError, err.m_strFileName);
}

do
{
    uNoOfBytes = fp.Read( pBuffer, DATA_CHUNK_SIZE );

    if( uNoOfBytes < DATA_CHUNK_SIZE )
    {
        bIsFinalBlock = true;               
    }

    uNoOfEncBytes = aes.Encrypt(pBuffer,(int)uNoOfBytes, bIsFinalBlock);

    if (!(bRet=InternetWriteFile( m_hRequest, (BYTE*)pBuffer, uNoOfEncBytes,NULL)))
    {
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();
        break;
    }

    if(bIsFinalBlock)
        break;

    }while ( uNoOfBytes != 0 ) ;

fp.Close();
```

Comment: Does any message come with that error-code? If so, please post that message too. Also, can you pin down the exact point in your code where the error occurs? If so, please mark it with a comment in your code.

Comment: No messages with error code. The error occurs at fp.Close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

"The connection with the server has been reset or terminated, or an incompatible SSL protocol was encountered. For example, WinHTTP version 5.1 does not support SSL2 unless the client specifically enables it."

Anyway, I don't see where you initialize m_hRequest. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that HINTERNET should be initialized with either function.